# PowerQuery conditional replace error values

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to execute a step in PowerQuery that replaces error values with one of two possible values.
The values in [B] would be 1 or 0 depending on the value of [A] (less than 5).

My statement returns a Function instead of a value, but I can't see why:

```
= Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Step x", {{"B", each if [A] < 5 then 0 else 1}})
```

I've used the same conditional syntax for simple .Replace statements, but I'm wondering if I can't put the condition in a curly braces list. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your issue, but I see you have double curly braces in your second parameter. They would be required if you were replacing errors in multiple columns. However, since you're replacing errors in only one column, single braces would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of creating the conditional clause in the `Table.ReplaceErrorValues()` function. I suspect it has something to do with how the iteration works.

The only workaround I could think of was to make the Table.ReplaceErrorValues() replace errors with a spurious value, -1 in my case, and then call the `ReplaceValue()` function, which can accept the conditional clause:

```
= Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Step x", -1)
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Errors",-1,each if [A] < 5 then 0 else 1,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"B"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Table.ReplaceErrorValues` you could instead use a `try`/`otherwise` wherever that "Error" value is being generated. For instance, if your previous step is...

```
#"Step x" = Table.AddColumn(#"Step y", "B", each [C] / [D]) // Error if [D] = 0!
```

... then you could change it to something like...

```
#"Step x" = Table.AddColumn(#"Step y", "B", each
    try [C] / [D]    // Error if [D] = 0!
    otherwise if [A] < 5 then 0 else 1)
```

This way, you never have the Error values in the first place!

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat idea. Unfortunately I have to demo the ReplaceErrorValues function in a course I'm giving, so I have to use that. See my answer for the only workaround I could find.